# Local React App gives No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' when trying to talk to Service behing nginx-ingress on Azure

Tags: node.js, axios, cors, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I know that this question has been asked very often. Please bear with me.

I have 2 deployments + services running on Azure AKS: react client and nodejs auth. I have registered a public IP on Azure which I added to my windows host file (= myexample.com). When everything is running in the cloud, I can access the client and successfully send requests go to auth service.

Now I want to run the client locally (with npm start) and connect to auth service still running on Azure.

When I use Postman with the `POST http://myexample.com/api/users/signin` with the correct email and password, I get my authorisation token back as expected.

When I open React app locally and try to sign in in Chrome, I get `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://myexample.com/api/users/signin' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I know I am getting this error because my local client has a different domain from the auth service running on Azure AKS.
I annotated my kubernetes to allow my localhost:3000 as origin

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  namespace: development
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "http://localhost:3000"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: myexample.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/users/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

I also added cors to my auth service

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.set('trust proxy', true);
app.use(json());
app.use(signinRouter);
```

My sign in call from the app looks as follows

```
login: ({ username, password }) => {
  let url = 'http://myexample.com/api/users/signin';
  const authData = {
    email: username,
    password: password,
  }
  return axios.post(url, authData)
    .then(response => {
      localStorage.setItem('userID', response.data.id);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      throw new Error(error.response.request.response);
    });
}
```

When sending the request from Chrome, the response header does not include any of the expected entries such as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. It looks like this:

```
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: text/html
date: Sun, 04 Dec 2022 21:47:40 GMT
server: NginX
transfer-encoding: chunked
vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Here is my request header:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,de;q=0.8,es;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-origin
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Connection: keep-alive
Host: myexample.com
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Looking at my ingress via `kubectl describe ing ingress-service -n development` gives me

```
Name:             ingress-service
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        development
Address:          20.73.25.100
Ingress Class:    <none>
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  myexample.com
              /api/users/?(.*)   auth-srv:3000 (10.221.0.67:3000)
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: true
              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS
              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: http://localhost:3000
              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: true
              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: true
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                  From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----                 ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    9m33s (x4 over 16m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

Looking at the logs of my ingress controller, I see the POST call coming from Postman but no new log entry when I try to sign in with the app.

Looking at the Nginx configuration, I see that the annotations have been added:

```
...
# Cors Preflight methods needs additional options and different Return Code

if ($http_origin ~* ((http://localhost:3000))$ ) { set $cors 'true'; }

if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
    set $cors ${cors}options;
}

if ($cors = "true") {
    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin';
    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true';
    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested- 
 With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization';

    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000';
}

if ($cors = "trueoptions") {
    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin';
    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true';
    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization';

    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000';
    more_set_headers 'Content-Type: text/plain charset=UTF-8';
    more_set_headers 'Content-Length: 0';
    return 204;
}
...
```

I also tried adding origin option to cors in my auth service as opposed to not passing any parameters when adding cors to express (as I described earlier). Same error as before.

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
}));
```

Why is this not working? Is there some Azure setting that needs changing? Am I missing code in the auth service level, ingress level, ... ? Is it something to do with axios? Or ssl?

Any help/pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: _`" http://localhost:3000"`_  there's an unwanted leading space here in your k8s config

Comment: The error suggests a problem with the pre-flight `OPTIONS` response. Is that what you're looking at in the Chrome dev-tools? Also, shouldn't your deployed service be available at an `https://` URL?

Comment: @phil, good spotting. That blank does not exist on my actual deployment. I must have accidentally added it when writing my question. I fixed it in the question

Comment: @phil. In Chrome DevTools I see two requests to signin. the 2nd call is the one from the reported headers and is of type pre-flight (Request URL: http://myexample.com/api/users/signin, Request Method: OPTIONS). The 1st call is to same request URL, Chrome is showing provisional headers with type xhr and status CORS error.
 There is a https:// configuration with a proper domain and https. This configuration with the client running locally is for development only. We need it for an external developer to work on the client and only on the client app.

Comment: What do the response headers (and body) look like for the `OPTIONS` request? Is the response status successful, ie `200`, `201`, etc?

Comment: The response header is also shown in my question (I added the ; for readability): HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden;
date: Sun, 04 Dec 2022 23:23:40 GMT; content-type: text/html;
transfer-encoding: chunked;
vary: Accept-Encoding;
server: NginX;
content-encoding: gzip)
There is no response body. Devtools saying 'Failed to load response data. no content available for preflight request'. The status is 403 Forbidden